# VBA to open explorer and select, not open, a selected file name

Tags: excel, select, explorer, vba

I want a macro to open windows explorer and just select a file but don’t want it to open the file.
I’ve got a list of document names in excel split into some variables.
I also included some hyperlinks in it, so you can directly open the selected file.
But now I want a macro that selects the corresponding file in explorer and just selects it.
All files are in a predefined location, but all filenames are different, off course.
Example; 
D:\username\Documents\workplans\document.001.1.xls 
D:\username\Documents\workplans\document.002.2.xls 
D:\username\Documents\workplans\document.003.3.xls

I want to select the corresponding file name in excel, and start the macro to select it in explorer.
So for example I select cell D3 and start the macro so it opens explorer and go’s to the following address and selects the file; D:\username\Documents\workplans\document.002.2.xls

```
      A                 B             C             D                 E
 1. var 1             var 2          var 3      doc. Name          Hyperlink
 2. document            1             1     document.001.1.xls  document.001.1
 3. document            2             2     document.002.2.xls  document.002.2
 4. document            3             3     document.003.3.xls  document.003.3
```

If I use the following code directly to the link it works like how I want it to be, but the file name is variable.

```
Sub open_explorer()
Shell "C:\Windows\explorer.exe /select,D:\username\Documents\workplans\document.002.2.xls", vbMaximizedFocus
End Sub
```

I adjusted the code, but it won’t work. I think the problem is in the (& range (activeCell.select)).
How do I get this to work?

```
Sub open_explorer()
Shell "C:\Windows\explorer.exe /select, D:\username\Documents\workplans\ &Range ActiveCell.Select", vbMaximizedFocus
End Sub
```

Answer (score 8):

Give this a try:

```
Sub open_explorer()
Shell "C:\Windows\explorer.exe /select, ""D:\username\Documents\workplans\" _
    & ActiveCell.Value & """", vbMaximizedFocus
End Sub
```

Note that quotes are required around any path that has spaces or other *special characters*. The **doubled quotes** in the string above, both before `D:` and after `ActiveCell.Value` (concatenated to the end of the string) puts a *double quote* char before and after the path.

Comment: @user3572958 If this is what you needed, please mark as answer. Thanks!

Comment: @GlennFromIowa Any idea, why for me it just opens the explorer, when I use the macro, but works like charm, if I use the command directly in the cmd window? (using Win10 & Office 2016)

Comment: @Phab My guess is that there may be spaces or other _special characters_ in the path name. if so, you need to surround the path with quotes. I have edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

The above only worked for me if I add an extension to the filename such as ".xls".

```
Sub open_explorer()
Shell "C:\Windows\explorer.exe /select, D:\username\Documents\workplans\" & ActiveCell.Value & ".xls", vbMaximizedFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: See also my post on: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/906667-visual-basic-applications-macro-open-explorer-select-file.html#post4361586

Comment: If you do not include the extension **in the filename** in the Active Cell, then yes, you would need to add the extension into the VBA string. If your extension **is** included in the ActiveCell.Value, like the OP's was, it will **not** find a file with the name, for example, `D:\username\Documents\workplans\document.001.1.xls.xls`